# Eigenvector of $A^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So the question is if $v$ is the eigenvector of $A^2$, then it's also the eigenvector of $A\,$ (so $A^2v=\lambda_1 v $, then $Av=\lambda_2v$).

I can prove it the other way certainly, I'm just not sure this way. My proof is this:
Let $Av=\lambda_2v$
$A^2v=A(Av)=A(\lambda_2v)=\lambda_2(Av)=\lambda_2^2 v$
Is this a valid proof? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not true.  For example, $\pmatrix{1\cr 1\cr}$ is an eigenvector of $\pmatrix{-1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr}^2$, but not of 
$\pmatrix{-1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr}$

Comment: Ah, this explains why I had such a hard time trying to prove it. Thanks!